# Share Rules in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I am using sitecore 7.1 on a large scale application, I want to start using rules to change content on the fly. However I have a lot of small renderings on a single page, inside placeholders, etc. IS there a method to share rules, yet their actions be different, and is there a top level way to switch between the rules and have the entire page react, through Page Editor.

Thanks

Comment: Share rules, as in per content item and not as part of the display details?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by saying share rules? Rules can be parametrised, so not sure is that something different?

Comment: I guess I want to be able to set with page editor using the persona card, that changes any content item to that matching rules. It's time consuming in a way to go one by one, add the rules over and over, when all I need is to say this RULE do this, and set that all over the place. And at the top have a persona card that triggers all those at one time.

Comment: Are you using MVC or Webforms?